# Join two dataframes in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have two data frames:

### df1

```
+----+----+
|key1|val1|
+----+----+
|a1  |   1|
|b1  |   2|
+----+----+
```

### df2

```
+----+----+
|key2|val2|
+----+----+
|a2  |   3|
|b2  |   4|
+----+----+
```

And then I want to merge these two data frames to get the following data frame:

### df3

```
+----+----+----+----+
|key1|val1|key2|val2|
+----+----+
|a1  |   1|a2  |   3|
|a1  |   1|b2  |   4|
|b1  |   2|a2  |   3|
|b1  |   2|b2  |   4|
+----+----+
```

How can I do this in PySaprk?

Answer (score 2):

Try `cross join` as below,

```
df3 = df1.crossJoin(df2)
df3.show()
```

This should give output as you want.